# How to do a "manage my pledge" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

*Not sure how to phrase my question. Feel free to edit the title.*

Background: crowdfunding app

Routes:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
  resources :campaigns, path: '' do
    resources :pledges
  end
end
```

Campaigns controller:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @campaign = Campaign.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @days_to_go = @campaign.days_to_live - ((Time.now - @campaign.created_at).to_i / 1.day)
    @total_shares_reserved = 0;
    @campaign.pledges.each do |pledge|
      @total_shares_reserved += pledge.shares_reserved
    end
    @amount_raised = number_to_currency(@total_shares_reserved * @campaign.share_price_cents / 100, unit: '', precision: 0)
    @amount_goal = number_to_currency(@campaign.shares_offered * @campaign.share_price_cents / 100, unit: '', precision: 0)
    @campaign_shares_available = @campaign.shares_offered - @total_shares_reserved
    @campaign_share_price_dollars = number_to_currency(@campaign.share_price_cents / 100, unit: '', precision: 0)
    @pledge = @campaign.pledges.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
  end
end
```

In my campaign show view I display a "Pledge" button if the logged in user has not made a pledge and a "Manage My Pledge" button if he had.

```
<%= link_to 'Manage Pledge', edit_user_campaign_pledge_path(@campaign.user, @campaign, @pledge) %>
```

The link shows up as:

```
http://localhost:3000/user-slug/campaign-slug/pledges/7/edit
```

**Question:**

How can I make it show up as:

```
http://localhost:3000/user-slug/campaign-slug/pledge/edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing your routes to:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
  resources :campaigns, path: '' do
    resource :pledges # note: singular `resource` here
  end
end
```

Read more about singular resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

And change route building to:

```
edit_user_campaign_pledge_path(@campaign.user, @campaign)
```

Comment: Almost there. I'm getting `http://localhost:3000/user-slug/campaign-slug/pledge/edit.7` (number at the end)

Comment: Got it working with `edit_user_campaign_pledge_path(@campaign.user, @campaign)`.